# Python - Write a row into an array into a text file

Tags: python, pandas

I have to work on a flat file (size > 500 Mo) and I need to create to split file on one criterion.
My original file as this structure (simplified):
JournalCode|JournalLib|EcritureNum|EcritureDate|CompteNum|

I need to create to file depending on the first digit from 'CompteNum'.

I have started my code as well

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

C_FILE_SEP = "|"

def main(fic):
    pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
    FileFec = pd.read_csv(fic, C_FILE_SEP, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

It seems ok, my concern is to create my 2 files based on criteria. I have tried with unsuccess.

```
TargetFec = 'Target_'+fic+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+'.txt'
target = open(TargetFec, 'w')
FileFec = FileFec.astype(convert_dict) 
for row in FileFec.iterrows():

Fec_Cpt = str(FileFec['CompteNum']) 
nb = len(Fec_Cpt)
if (nb > 7):
    target.write(str(row))
target.close()
```

the result of my target file is not like I expected:

```
(0, JournalCode                              OUVERT
JournalLib                 JOURNAL D'OUVERTURE 
EcritureNum                          XXXXXXXXXX
EcritureDate                           20190101
CompteNum                                101300
CompteLib                  CAPITAL SOUSCRIT    
CompAuxNum                                     
CompAuxLib                                     
PieceRef                   XXXXXXXXXX          
PieceDate                              20190101
EcritureLib      A NOUVEAU                     
Debit                           000000000000,00
Credit                          000038188458,00
EcritureLet                                 NaN
DateLet                                     NaN
ValidDate                              20190101
Montantdevise                                  
Idevise                                        
CodeEtbt                                    100
Unnamed: 19                                 NaN
```

And I expected to obtain line into my target file when CompteNum(0:1) > 7

I have read many posts for 2 days, please some help will be perfect.

There is a sample of my data available [here](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ9HhkVZ0V8T341JtFfg1McfOXdbsYnXd3ly)

Philippe

Comment: Can you make the data available, or part of it? Your logic seems incorrect.

Comment: I have edited my original post to give a link with original data. I'm sure my logic is wrong but I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: I tried to run the code snippet left, but I was not successful. Some variables are missing and your function is returning None. See the answer I left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suiting the rules and the desired format, you can use logic like:

```
# criteria:
verify = df['CompteNum'].apply(lambda number: str(number)[0] == '8' or str(number)[0] == '9')

# saving the dataframes:
df[verify].to_csv('c:/users/jack/desktop/meets-criterios.csv', sep = '|', index = False)
```

---

Original comment:

As I understand it, you want to filter the imported dataframe according to some criteria. You can work directly on the pandas you imported. Look:

```
# criteria:
verify = df['CompteNum'].apply(lambda number: len(str(number)) > 7)

# filtering the dataframe based on the given criteria:
df[verify] # meets the criteria
df[~verify] # does not meet the criteria

# saving the dataframes:
df[verify].to_csv('<your path>/meets-criterios.csv')
df[~verify].to_csv('<your path>/not-meets-criterios.csv')
```

Once you have the filtered dataframes, you can save them or convert them to other objects, such as dictionaries.

Comment: Like I'm a newbie, I would like understand, the function verify = df['CompteNum'].apply(lambda number: len(str(number)) > 7) -->test if the first digit of CompteNum is higher than 7, isn't.

Comment: Welcome @Philippegauthier! Verify is actually a series (vector) which is the result of pandas apply method. What you have is a booleaning vector which is later used to filter your dataframe. But that's basically what he said. Don't forget to approve the answer, if correct =).

Comment: I have approved it, i have not finished my case. Base on my test file, I see there is a true or false value for verify, but it's given True with a CompteNum starting by 1 ...

Comment: I have run your code: my output file is starting by index and I need to have as separator the |

Comment: Tell pandas what the separator is at save time `df[verify].to_csv('<your path>/meets-criterios.csv', sep = '|')`

Comment: The lambda function it's not working, CompteNum ie = 1102122 --> and function is true. my goal is to take in consideration the first digit and verify = FileFec['CompteNum'].apply(lambda number: len(str(number[0:1])) > 7)

Comment: How so @Philippegauthier? What are the rules? I thought it was to consider only numbers with more than 7 digits.

Comment: The field CompteNum contains numbers like 103120 or 707010343, and some starting by 8 or 9. In case there are starting by 8 or 9 I need to save it into file2, otherwise in file 1. Also, the first column is equal to the index, I need to remove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242173/discussion-between-jassis-and-philippe-gauthier).

Comment: To finish, with help of @jassis I solved all my issue.
First point: CompteNum:
`verify = FileFec['CompteNum'].apply(lambda number: int(number[0]) > 7)`
To drop column unnammed:
`FileFec = FileFec.drop("Unnamed: 19", axis=1)`
To save data without index and with a separator in the end of line
`FileFec[verify].to_csv(TargetFec9, sep = C_FILE_SEP, index = False, line_terminator = '|\n')`